# CEWE fotobook service crashes after kernel update

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel

I am running Ubuntu Studio. 
Today I upgraded my kernel version. My old version:
Linux version 4.10.0-42-lowlatency (buildd@lgw01-amd64-007) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) ) #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 4 17:13:40 UTC 2017

For improved security got an advise to upgrade. The upgrade is:
Linux version 4.13.0-26-lowlatency (buildd@lgw01-amd64-031) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5)) #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 9 22:52:31 UTC 2018

Now I have problems starting up "kruidvat fotoservice" sw. That's originated from CEWE. The program starts, shows a GUI and after a short while it hangs.  When I try to close it I get a message that the system is busy. After that the mouse is not responding. 
I switched to a terminal (F2) and after login the system started continiously generating the next message:
nouveau 000:23:00.0: XORG[1519]: nv50cal_space: -16. 
Hard switch off was the only solution to get out of this state.
When starting up with the old Kernel (4.10.0-42) the "kruidvat" program is running fine. (I also have the CEWE SW installed wich has the same problem.) Does anyone has a clue for a solution (besides running under the old kernel)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try kernel 4.14.13 the latest mainline (stable) version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work out. I installed linux-image-4.14.13. The program starts and shortly after startup it loads some semi transparant layer with product views. After that the program freezes. The mouse is not able to select anything anymore. Not even icons on my desktop or menubar.

Comment: If you want the security enhancements on an older kernel that may work with your app you can try `4.9.76`